# Other devices on same network unable to access Wordpress localhost setup

Tags: localhost

I have wordpress installed in a sub-directory "www" on my laptop using XAMPP 7.3.0-0 (OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop).

On my laptop, I can access it through `http://localhost/www/` or `http://192.168.8.200/www/` (after changing `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in `wp-config.php` to replace localost with IP address).

**The Problem:**

When I access `http://192.168.8.200/www/` from other devices, it redirects me to `http://localhost/www/` saying

> This site cannot be reached
>   localhost refused to connect.

I can access other sub-directories like `http://192.168.8.200/ABC/` and `http://192.168.8.200/XYZ/` on same server without any issue.

**Information that may help to resolve the problem**

This is `.htaccess` file in "www" directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /www/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`wp-config.php` setting:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://192.168.8.200/www' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://192.168.8.200/www' );
```

1. How can I access `http://192.168.8.200/www/` from other devices on
   same network? Any clue...
2. How can I use my computer name instead of static IP?

Thanks

Comment: maybe a solution here will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122583/website-in-wordpress-redirects-to-old-url-after-migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122583/website-in-wordpress-redirects-to-old-url-after-migration

In particular, I'd check these two:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873881/1577662

> be sure to clear your cache and use this script to replace ALL urls in
>   your database.
>
> https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

And https://stackoverflow.com/a/41223768/1577662

> In case you are using Polylang with a dynamic IP, add
>   define('PLL_CACHE_HOME_URL', false); in your wp-config.php and it will
>   solve all your problems (redirection to the former url)!

Or if you're just setting up, perhaps the easiest path forward may be to start over and use the ip address from the start on a brand new installation.

Re: How can I use my computer name instead of static IP?  You would need to have name resolution set up internally, if you run local DNS servers this would work, or you could edit the local `hosts` files on the servers that need to access the site.

Comment: Thanks @user16081 , clearing browser cache resolved the issue.